# ESP32 WiFi-Mesh HTTPS request

Tags: https, esp32, esp-idf, mesh-network

I am working on an ESP32 project using the ESP-IDF development framework. I have setup Mesh networking using the esp_mesh library which is currently working. I am now trying to implement OTA updates into my project in which all boards in the network will be updated with new firmware from my server.

Using the esp_http_client I have been able to do a HTTPS request (status code 200) when using a normal WiFi connection, however, when I run my mesh network then try to perform the HTTPS request the same thing is not working (I get status code 202). I have put the error logs i get below:

```
E (19444) esp-tls: couldn't get hostname for :url: getaddrinfo() returns 202, addrinfo=0x0
E (19444) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (19444) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection
E (19454) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (19454) Mesh OTA: HTTPS request for OTA update failed ESP_ERR_HTTP_CONNECT
```

This problem still occurs when running off the root node which is not what I'd expect. Does anyone know how to get the esp_http_client library to work when using the mesh library?

I've tried the request using a normal WiFi connection, and it works as expected. Now i am trying to  perform the request from the root node, to download the new firmware from my server. Which I can then distribute across my mesh network. My internal communication between boards in the network works fine, it's just the external connection that doesn't work.